# Checkout new brach from master with remote Android Studio 4.0

Tags: git, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-studio-4.0

On Android Studio, when using Git as version control, there is a `Git Branches` tab at the bottom right of the screen.

[image: Git Branches tab on Android Studio]

On previous versions, you could click a remote branch, and choose `Checkout as` to checkout a new local branch that automatically has that branch as the remote.

Now in Android Studio 4.0, the menu changed, and the available option named `New Branch from Selected...` allows a similar behavior but without setting the remote configuration. So in this case I need to manually call this command to set it.
`git branch --set-upstream-to origin/master`

I'm not sure if this is Android Studio or a general Intellij change, but is there a way to get the same behavior as before in the GUI without having to manually set the remote for the new branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set a tracking branch to a local one you can just push and you will see how origin/branch will appear in Branches pop-up.

If you have a tracking branch and you would like to check it out locally, then click on remote branch and click "Checkout".

Also, this ticket can be helpful:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-228145#focus=streamItem-27-3836864.0-0

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize the `Checkout` option would make a local branch with the same name as the remote and track it correctly. And thanks for pointing out the YouTrack issue, since having the functionality to use `New Branch from Selected...` and track the branch at the same time is not possible.